# Как в JS выполнить вызов функции после выполнения innerHTML (обновления DOM)?

Tags: javascript

Есть div-контейнер модального окна, содержимое которого загружается через AJAX. Далее (после загрузки содержимого) определяется его высота в зависимости от которой выравнивается модальное окно.

```
document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = ajax_html;
...
var height = document.getElementById('modal').clientHeight;
```

Функции выполняются одновременно из-за чего высота модального окна начинает определяться еще до загрузки в него содержимого (и обновления DOM-дерева).

Такой трюк позволяет решить проблему, но выглядит не слишком изящно в коде.

```
document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = ajax_html;
...
setTimeout(function() {
    var height = document.getElementById('modal').clientHeight;
    ...
}, 20);
```

Каким образом можно вызвать вторую функцию (определение высоты) только после завершения DOM-операции (innerHTML) в первой?

Comment: ваша терминология не является общепринятой. вы называете синхронное асинхронным и наоборот.

Comment: @vp_arth да, что-то намудрил, сейчас поправил текст. но вопрос все же остался)

Comment: a `ajax_html` содержит только html?

Comment: @Igor да, в этой переменной html код, полученный из ajax-запроса

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov я хотел сказать - в этом html скриптов нет?

Comment: @Igor нет, там просто код. причем самое интересное, в большинстве случаев innerHTML выполняется синхронно, но в некоторых блоках происходит преждевременный вызов функции определение высоты. экспериментировал с величиной таймаута (setTimeout). все стабильно начинает работать, когда он больше 20 мс, если меньше, высота определяется по блоку с незагруженным кодом.

Comment: Пора уже использовать css для центрирования.

Comment: @Qwertiy не все так просто. там в зависимости от высоты применяются различные схемы вертикального выравнивания. если блок маленький, то позиционирование идет не ровно посередине, а немного выше центра (так смотрится более гармоничнее). если блок большой, то позиционирование выполняется по центру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Функции выполняются одновременно

Всё выполняется последовательно - HTML помещается в контейнер, затем уже от HTML внутри контейнера высчитывается высота. Другое дело, что в HTML могут быть картинки, которые после загрузки действительно меняют размер - у картинок есть событие загрузки изображения, если это так. Также с этим HTML могут поработать какие-либо скрипты после вызова `var height = ...` что приведёт к изменению размера: тут уже смотреть причину в коде самостоятельно. Но одновременно ничего не выполняется.

Можно ещё делать попапы чисто на CSS3 - тогда высчитывать высоту вовсе не потребуется.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно что-то вроде этого :

```
function new (node, data, callback) { 
    node = data;
    callback();
}

function callback (node){
    var height = node.clientHeight;
}
```

Comment: да, уже пробовал подобное. но результат тот же, вторая функция отрабатывает до завершения обновления DOM-дерева.